# When to use Threads or Parallel to get HTTPWebRequests in order, in sync

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, parallel-processing

I’m trying to write a VB.net (framework 4.5) that will see if 1000 Proxy servers are up and I want to process them in batches of 10 at a time. 
I’ve tried using threads, threadpool and have drawn a blank so have now moved onto using a Parallel method however the output is not in order.

```
Public Sub Get_Items_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Get_Items_Button.Click

    Dim ParallelOpts As New ParallelOptions()
    ParallelOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10

    Parallel.For(0, 2000, ParallelOpts, AddressOf ProxySub)


End Sub

Public Sub ProxySub(ByVal ItemNumber As Integer)

 ‘Do some work … See if Proxy is up and running using HTTPWebRequest and output to a SyncLock textbox


End sub
```

The ProxySub makes a HTTPWebRequest on to different servers so I understand that the order in which they return will not always be in the same order in which they are sent however I need sync the output.

Also if the “ParallelOpts.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10” is set then why am I seeing the output jump from 0 to 40?

The output would be as follows;
0, 40, 5, 63, 7, 23, 1, 9, and so on.

How can I sync it so the output would be in order, i.e.;
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on.

Many thanks for any input you can give

Answer (score 0):

It's not sufficient to synclock your textbox. You need to make the change on the UI thread.

```
Public Sub ProxySub(ByVal ItemNumber As Integer)

    'Do some work … See if Proxy is up and running using HTTPWebRequest and output to a SyncLock textbox

    OnResultReceived(new MyResultObject(itemNumber, data))

End Sub

Public Sub OnResultReceived(result As MyResultObject)
    'Any thread can call this
    If InvokeRequired Then
        'It wasn't the UI thread. Call this method again from the ui thread.
        Me.BeginInvoke(Sub() OnResultReceived(result))
    Else
        'This is now on the ui thread
        'Add the sorted results to the textbox
        TextBox.Text = ...
    End If
End Sub
```

To add the text in order you could store the results in a sortedlist and use string.join or change the textbox into a listview which can handle the sorting.

Comment: Hi FloatingKiwi
Thanks for your input, it’s very much appreciated. Since posting I have realised my approach was not the best and I have now had some success using an ‘Await AsyncHTTPWeb’.